# Get position of a row in a table, when ordered by name asc

Tags: php, mysql

I am displaying information from a table with pagination, say 30 rows per page, and order by name asc.

I need to know **in which page** a given row is, I have the id and name of that. Wondering if that is possible.

Thanks guys.

Comment: If there are no missing IDs in the table (e.g. deleted rows) you could just query count(*) and calculate the page.

Comment: Yes but I will surely have missing ids, data get deleted in most tables.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is nice behavior but you could add a "WHERE id < $id" and use this value to calculate the page number? Edit: Sorry don't use the ID, you said you use order by name. search for the name instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say the id is 'john'

```
select count(*)
from tbl
where name <= 'john'
order by name asc
```

Counting all the names, including 'john' gives you the position of john when sorted by name asc.  Divide this by the rows-per-page and you will have the page number.

Comment: But you could not do this in 1 query for all names.

Comment: Yep, cool idea. `$pageNumber = ceil(($rowPosition / $postPerPage));`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a counter like this:

```
 set @i = 0; 
 select id, @i:=@i+1 as myrow from yourTableName
```

If you want to know where, for instance, id=130 is, you look to the linked "myrow". If that is 11, then it is on page 1. if it is on 35, it is on page 2, etc.

Comment: I'd like to know why this got a -1 ? It might work differently from cyberkiwi's answer, but is usefull nonetheless. Depending on if you get multiple names and want to know where they should link, or if you just have gotten 1 name.

Comment: @Nanne: Probably because that wasn't the question. It's about a single row. Still you get a +1 from me. Your code will probably be relevant to other people looking at this question.

Comment: I don't know. It talks about a "given row", but if it is about a given row that was collected with a query, above row can give you the pagenumber for (for instance) a detail page (with 30 per page) from a "everything" page (with all names).

Comment: @nikic selecting whole table to get only position of one row is just terrible practice. this code will never be useful but deceiving

Comment: Again, this code IS usefull if you allready HAVE that table, is my point. I interpreted the question as "I'm getting the information from a table, and also wish to know what position something is going to get". To randomly call an answer "bad practicy" because you interpret the situation differently feels uncalled for? I agree you COULD do something unwanted with this, but that's not what I am suggesting.

Comment: Thanks Nanne, I found that Richard's reply is probably more adapted to my case. I am still giving +1 to you, considering this would be useful in a different situation.